# using IF ELSE in sql server (what to put in the IF statement)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using the IF statement to insert data into ProductTable(using this name as an example) so how do i open the IF statement... the below calls the IF query but never reaches the else, which would be if it does exist in the table so here is an example of where I am at the moment. my error lies within the IF statement at the start but I cant work out what to put in to make it work

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 ProductID FROM ProductTable)
BEGIN
    INSERT
    (ProductName, UnitPrice)
        SELECT
        ProductView.ProductName,
        ProductView.UnitPrice
    FROM ProductView
    INNER JOIN ProductTable ON ProductView.ProductID = ProductTable. ProductID
    WHERE ProductID = (SELECT TOP 1 ProductID FROM ProductTable ORDER BY changedate DESC)
    AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM ProductTable WHERE ProductView.ProductID = ProductTable.ProductID)
END
ELSE
    INSERT
    (ProductName, UnitPrice)
        SELECT
        ProductView.ProductName,
        UnitPrice = 0.00
    FROM ProductView
    INNER JOIN ProductTable ON ProductView.ProductID = ProductTable. ProductID
    WHERE ProductID = (SELECT TOP 1 ProductID FROM ProductTable ORDER BY changedate DESC)
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? The syntax should be http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx. I think you can also use it like ````IF (1=1) BEGIN Select 'If - True' END ELSE BEGIN Select 'Else - False' END````

Comment: if 1=1 works submit that as an answer... just general syntax errors because i didnt know how to use an IF statement in SQL Server

Comment: do you just want to ensure that such an entry exists in the table? you could check `IF (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM ...) IS NOT NULL` for example

Comment: so what is problem with updated code?

Comment: You dont seem to be comparing the select statement to anything so this does is probably your error.  It should possibly be something like    IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Table1', 'U') IS NOT NULL BEGIN .. END ELSE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM Table1

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN

   -- Do stuff

END
```

Comment: will this detect if the ReferenceID exists or not? based on that depends on whether its the IF query or the ELSE query that is called

Comment: @Crezzer7 where are referenceId from your ctequery?

Comment: What is referenceId?  Are you trying to check if a table exists?  Or a value in a table?

Answer (score 0):

this is what I was after:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT ProductTable.CustomerReference FROM ProductTable)
BEGIN
something
END
ELSE
something else
```

I didn't need to include the TOP 1 and also I was missing a relationship which referenced it to the main table